# How do I input information for several records with one submission?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am beginner to ASP.NET Core MVC 6.0. Following a tutorial from the Microsoft learning site, I created the "Contoso University" project. In this project, when I add the new student, head to "create new" and input information of on person. It walked one by one.

However, I want to input information of several persons at one time. For example, first I fill several records and click the submit button.

How can I do it?

I can not find my way.

Comment: Your Controller method would recieve a List<Person> instead of Person. The view would need to be updated to add the properties to an array

Comment: You may create additional form fields (student2, student3, ...) or create a facility to upload a CSV, JSON, or something to do a mass insert of a List of Persons.

Comment: Hello have you tried the solution provided?  Is there anything else that I can help you on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to input information of several persons at one time. For
> example, first I fill several records and click the submit button.

Well, actually, based on your scenario and requirement you should create a list of student object inside the [asp form tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-7.0#the-form-tag-helper) which require a bit knowledge of javascript.

Within the form you would have a button which would include new dom for student object in the table. Finally, you can post to your controller where you would define list of student as parameter.

Let's have a look in practice, how we can achieve that:

Model:

```cs
public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }
        public string? LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```cs
<form method="post" asp-controller="Student" asp-action="Create">
    <div style="padding-bottom:20px">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AddNewStudentFunc()">Add New Student</button>
    </div>

    <div id="dataTable">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="StudenetList" data-count="0">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" />
</form>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        /*
             . I am Hidding table on load
        */
        document.getElementById('dataTable').style.display = 'none';

        function AddNewStudentFunc() {
            var countVal = parseInt($('#StudenetList').attr('data-count'));
            var html = '';
            html += '<tr>';
            html += '<td><input type="text" name="Student[' + countVal + '].FirstName" class="form-control"/></td>';
            html += '<td><input type="text" name="Student[' + countVal + '].LastName" class="form-control"/></td>';
            html += '<td><input type="text" name="Student[' + countVal + '].Age" class="form-control"/></td>';
            html += '</tr>';

            $('#StudenetList').append(html);
            countVal += 1;
            $('#StudenetList').attr('data-count', countVal);
            /*
               . Showing table when adding item into it
            */
            document.getElementById('dataTable').style.display = 'block';

        }
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(List<Student> student)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               
            }
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View("Create");
            }
            //Save your student list into database
            //_context.Studnet.AddRange(student);
            //_context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return View("Create");
        }
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note:**  If you need [more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud?view=aspnetcore-7.0), you could [check our official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Mr.Md Farid Uddin Kiron!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Mr.Md Farid Uddin Kiron! It works. This is first time to meet javascript code for me. I ask you how I can study the issue like this. From where to start?Which book is the best? Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Thanks for your response, a lot of tutorial available online your can try out. Just know the basic first gradually, you could learn advance topic.